# Tesserocr installation on Mac M1

Tags: python, macos, tesseract, leptonica

I have tried a lot, but still, I don't know why unable to install `Tesserocr` and `leptonica` on Mac M1. the `error` is here, thanks for your help.

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Users/mahdiseify/opt/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/yz/5nlp05fj4_555yk6l3wrwcrc0000gn/T/pip-install-g9egkz3i/tesseract-ocr/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/yz/5nlp05fj4_555yk6l3wrwcrc0000gn/T/pip-install-g9egkz3i/tesseract-ocr/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/yz/5nlp05fj4_555yk6l3wrwcrc0000gn/T/pip-wheel-698gyerl
       cwd: /private/var/folders/yz/5nlp05fj4_555yk6l3wrwcrc0000gn/T/pip-install-g9egkz3i/tesseract-ocr/
  Complete output (15 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  file tesseract_ocr.py (for module tesseract_ocr) not found
  file tesseract_ocr.py (for module tesseract_ocr) not found
  running build_ext
  building 'tesseract_ocr' extension
  creating build
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/mahdiseify/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/mahdiseify/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/mahdiseify/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c tesseract_ocr.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/tesseract_ocr.o
  tesseract_ocr.cpp:643:10: fatal error: 'leptonica/allheaders.h' file not found
  #include "leptonica/allheaders.h"
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  1 error generated.
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for tesseract-ocr
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like that the leptonica-related includes are not in the includes-path of gcc. Check their location and then extend
$C_INCLUDE_PATH accordingly.